# Angularjs - $http request does not work from inside a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, http

In the controller i would like to put the http request of a json file into a function. Only when its outside of a function it works. Why?
I would like to display the contents in the view.

Controller:

```
$http.get('components/json/list.json').success(function (data) {
    main.listNoFunction = data;
});

main.listFunction = function () {
    var result = null;
    $http.get('components/json/list.json').success(function (data) {
        result = data;
    });
    return result;
}
```

View:

```
// This works:
{{ main.listNoFunction }}

// This works NOT:
{{ main.listFunction }}
```

Thanks for your help! 
Vin

Comment: This will return always null, $http is async. You must return a promise or set the result inside a scope variable.

Answer (score 5):

you need to call the function, not just reference its object name.

example:

```
{{ main.listFunction() }}
```

Also, $http is asynchronous, meaning that the result of the function will be returned before the $http call is finished.

I suggest you read up on promises at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q to achieve the desired effect.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason why the second example would work. Here is the explanation of the both snippets.

**Snippet #1**.

```
$http.get('components/json/list.json').success(function (data) {
    main.listNoFunction = data;
});
```

This code put in the controller issues GET request. When response is available (remember that this is asynchronous operation, so `$http.get` returns immediately), execution enters into `success` callback. Inside of it `controllerAs` (`main`) property `listNoFunction` is populated. Then `$http.get` kicks off new digest loop, which applies scope objects and refreshes the view. You see data rendered properly.

**Snippet #2**.

```
main.listFunction = function () {
    var result = null;
    $http.get('components/json/list.json').success(function (data) {
        result = data;
    });
    return result;
}
```

First of all, you didn't call the function `main.listFunction`. But even if you did, result would still be the same. Once again, `$http.get` doesn't wait until server responds, so entire `main.listFunction` returns `undefined`. When later data comes into `success` callback and `result` is set - it's *too late* because it will not be reflected in the view anyway, since `result` was passed by value not reference.

Comment: Okay, this is a little confusing to me since i dont understand the use of the $http.get request this way. 
So how is it then possible to have a function returned the value of the $http.get request?

I read about the $resource service, maybe this is a better choice?

Comment: *"So how is it then possible to have a function returned the value of the $http.get request?"* It's not possible, because you can't return from AJAX request. `$http.get` returns a Promise object. This object provides an interface to set up a callback functions that will be called once data has come from the server. The same with `$resourse`.

Comment: Ok - In other words: I'd like to write a function that simply returns the content of a JSON file (whether with or without the $http.get ). 
Is there a simple way to do that?